# bash script - spawn, send, interact - commands not found error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I my shell script, I am trying to remove password prompt for `scp` command (as given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459182/using-expect-to-pass-a-password-to-ssh/459225#459225) and this is what I have so far :-

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn scp $DESTINATION_PATH/exam.tar $SSH_CREDENTIALS':/'$PROJECT_INSTALLATION_PATH
expect "password:"
send $sshPassword"\n";
interact
```

On running the script, I am getting errors

```
spawn: command not found
send: command not found
interact: command not found
```

I was also getting error `expect: command not found` also, then I realised the path to `expect` was not correct and `expect` was not installed at all. So, I did `yum install expect`, corrected the path and the error was gone. But not able to remove the other 3 errors still.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're invoking the script badly.

If you say:

```
bash scriptname
```

then the #! line is ignored and bash takes the file as though it were bash instructions.  But this is not a bash script, it's an expect script.

The #! line is only ever interpreted by the kernel, when given the script as a command to run in its own right.

Either give the script execute permission, so that you can just invoke `./scriptname`, or use the `expect` command to start the script.

Comment: Now I get expect command not found.

Comment: Did you specify the full path to the expect command, or use `env` to invoke it?
`#!/usr/bin/env expect` should be fairly portable.  `#!/usr/bin/expect` might be correct on some systems.  And can you invoke the `expect` command at a shell prompt?  If not, did somebody remove the package?  Try reinstalling it, if so.

Comment: Prompt and excellent answer!

Answer (score 9):

1. make sure you have "expect" tool before, if not, do it

   `# apt-get install expect`
2. create the a script file with following content. (# vi /root/scriptfile)

   `spawn scp /path_from/file_name user_name_here@to_host_name:/path_to`

   `expect "password:"`

   `send put_password_here\n;`

   `interact`
3. execute the script file with "expect" tool

   `# expect /root/scriptfile`